# Event handling in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

Is there any way to handle the MongoDB events/MongoDB Listner?

Requirement - I have to call java function on any insert/update in MongoDB ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not yet, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-124 , of course I am unsure if that is what you are truly asking

Comment: i  looked at spring AbstractMongoEventListener...but didnt understand the way to use it :(

Comment: What libraries are you using in Java to talk to MongoDB?  Just the Java driver on its own, or something else like Spring Data or MongoJack?